# A problem concerning Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is the following true for Lebesgue outer measure?

$\forall i\in\mathbb{N}^+,A_i\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$,then

$$m^*(\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}^+}A_i)=\lim_{N\to\infty}m^*(\bigcap_{i=1}^NA_i)$$

Comment: You might be interested in [continuity from above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Measures_of_infinite_intersections_of_measurable_sets).

Comment: @DylanMoreland Thanks for your link!That really helps me.

Answer (score 4):

No. Take $A_n=[n,\infty)$.

Extra characters.

Comment: Dear Alex,thank for your counterexample.Now I think if such extreme situation are deleted ,the conclusion could be true,according to @Dylan Moreland 's [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29#Measures_of_infinite_intersections_of_measurable_sets)